# Knockout observable with datalist not working correctly in Edge

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, html-datalist

Selecting an option from an HTML5 `<datalist>` does not update the observable property in Edge. In Chrome it updates the observable immediately after clicking the option, and in IE it updates the observable on blur.

I have a demo of this issue [here](https://liveweave.com/0aTMai). I am using this site because jsfiddle is blocked at my work..

What can I do here to ensure the observable is updated properly in Edge?

Edit: I just discovered from a co-worker that this works on an older version of Edge.

It works on Edge 40.15063.674.0/EdgeHTML 15.15063, which is my co-workers version, and doesn't work on Edge 41.16299.726.0/EdgeHTML 16.16299, which is my version.